# Loading data from BigQuery into Google Sheets using the command line

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, bq

I am looking for a way to upload data from Big Query into Google Sheets using the bq command line. Could not find any relevant documentation on the topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can export a table in BigQuery to a CSV file using command line, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types. Not sure if there is command line to load a CSV into Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, in that you would like to execute a query using the bq command and have the results saved to a Google Sheet, that is not possible currently.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#saving-query-results-to-sheets

The documented option in the above link is to essentially use the UI and save the results after they are executed.